# Eclipse Failed to Load JNI Shared Library in Windows 8,1

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jvm, java-native-interface

I am using Windows 8.1 64bit and x64 Architecture and Eclipse Luna Standard Version(Latest)** When I extract my Eclipse and Started it it is giving this error.

i don't know what to do However my **Eclipse.ini** look like this

```
 -startupplugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
 --launcher.library
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
 -product
 org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize512M
 -showsplash
  org.eclipse.platform
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize512M
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 --launcher.appendVmargs
 -vmargs
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
 -Xms40m
 -Xmx512m
```

I need **Help** :)

Comment: you did put the java jdk in a directory with no spaces instead of Program Files, right?

Comment: actually no ... Its kind of Like this C:/ProgramFiles(x86)/Java/jre/bin ...